# Laravel installed but confusion remains

Tags: laravel-4, installation

I have ubuntu 14.04 and LAMPP is installed. I was learning Laravel 4, but get a lot of confusion on it's documentation, below I list few of issue.

How to install laravel?

#### what I did :

copy github repository into `/opt/lampp/htdocs/larva` and run `composer install`, Laravel is installed and I can access it with `http://localhost/larva`

What is **homestead**? is that another way to install laravel or this is additional thing?

What is **artisan**? if I use artisan then do we need to use homestead also?

#### what I did ( in terminal )

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/larva
php artisan serve
```

it started the service and I can access laravel with htpp://localhost:8000 BUT if i close this terminal then URL is lost

and there is one other way is using vagrant?  do we need to use vagrant if we installed it already?

one more thing is Nginx?

overall these vagrant, Nginx, Homestead, artisan,and composer methods create such a mess.

Please clear the clouds and please do not mention what is vagrant Nginx and all. I just want to know that do I need to do something with Homestead and vagrant if i have installed using git repository and composer way?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Homestead is an official, pre-packaged Vagrant "box" that provides you a wonderful development environment without requiring you to install PHP, a web server, and any other server software on your local machine.
Artisan is the name of the command-line interface included with Laravel. It provides a number of helpful commands for your use while developing your application. It is driven by the powerful Symfony Console component.

When you close the terminal, you are stopping the service on port 8000. You always can create a virtual host, and point its root to your larval installation /public directory

you dont have to use vagrant to run laravel. Vagrant is just your 'bridge' to Virtual Mashine. 
If you installed LAravel via composer and you got it work on localhost:8000 then you dont need neither homestead or vagrant